# How does an email have my name? How can I change it?

Tags: email

I have an email address. When I send emails from it somehow my real name is included. My profile from that service has never included my full name. But it is somehow present. I tried changing my profile to something else, but it has no effect, inspecting the original message in gmail, still has my name in the `From` field. Can I change this? How could it have gotten my name?

I am deliberately being vague here, because I don't want to dox myself. And yes, I realize this may make it harder to answer some of the questions.

Ultimately I want to remove my name from being sent out with every email.

Comment: Are you sure this simply isn't the service creating a contact card for yourself?  Are you 100% sure your full name is actually being revealed when the recipient receives your email?

Comment: @Ramhound As noted in the body, when viewing the original message in gmail, which includes all headers and metadata, the name is present in the `From` field.

Comment: Are you viewing the header for the email you sent or the header of the email that was received? There is a huge difference.

Comment: Both. I scoured all the settings and found a field in the service that contains a name associated with that address, separate from the profile. Changing this prevents my name from going out. I have no idea how it got there. Email is one of the pieces of technology I understand the least so I felt lost. Well, I'm still lost, just a tiniest bit less now.

Comment: Your question can be reopened if the question is edited in order to make it clear.  It was probably closed due to the fact, you ended up finding out, that the account profile was indeed configured to your actual name.  Of course if this was about Google mail it probably should have just been stated was the case so it could be migrated to Web Applications SE instead of being closed as unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Your client and the recipients client will both remember your name if you have sent from and to these before, even if you remove your name from your account. Your control ends when the email leaves your server.

Want more anonymity? The correct thing to do is to create a new email address with a privacy focused service and use that in a different client, if you are using a client.

Answer (score 0):

In your email application, make the Name to be your email address. Use the first name field and omit the Surname.

This is in addition to the email field which also has your email address.

Using your email address in both places will solve the problem for you.

Going forward, if you do the above, you have no real name in your email profile, so then it should not go out.

Comment: If the recipient already has an address book entry with Ops name and email, it won't make a difference.

Comment: That is true. It will take time for a go forward way to work. It would be much more aggravation to me to change my email address. No simple solution here.